# columns converted to radio buttons

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
            <apex:column >

                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
    <APEX:PAGEBlock > 
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!con}" var="c"></apex:pageBlockTable>
    </APEX:PAGEBlock>
</apex:form>
```

above is my vf page.and below controller

```
public class wrapperClassController {

public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}

    public List<cContact> getContacts() {
    if(contactList == null) {
        contactList = new List<cContact>();
        for(Account c: [select Id, Name from Account limit 10]) {
            contactList.add(new cContact(c));
        }
    }
    return contactList;
}

public PageReference processSelected() {

    List<Account> selectedContacts = new List<Account>();

    for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
        if(cCon.selected == true) {
            selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
        }
    }

    System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
    for(Account con: selectedContacts) {
        system.debug(con);
    }
    contactList=null; 
    return null;
}

public class cContact {

    public Account con {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public cContact(Account c) {
        con = c;
        selected = false;
    }
}
}
```

if i check the checkboxes and click on "click to show selected radio value" selected checkbox value has to be displayed, please help me to do. thanks in advance,giving error like Error

> Error: Unknown property 'wrapperClassController.con'   Quick Fix  Create
>   Apex property 'sahi__wrapperClassController.con' Quick Fix    Create Apex
>   method 'sahi__wrapperClassController.getCon'

please help how to fix

Comment: Can you provide more details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wrapper class here. This is the best option in your use case. I am adding some sample code taken from Salesforce docs.

```
public class wrapperClassController {
//Our collection of the class/wrapper objects cContact 
public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}

//This method uses a simple SOQL query to return a List of Contacts
public List<cContact> getContacts() {
    if(contactList == null) {
        contactList = new List<cContact>();
        for(Contact c: [select Id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact limit 10]) {
            // As each contact is processed we create a new cContact object and add it to the contactList
            contactList.add(new cContact(c));
        }
    }
    return contactList;
}


public PageReference processSelected() {

            //We create a new list of Contacts that we be populated only with Contacts if they are selected
    List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

    //We will cycle through our list of cContacts and will check to see if the selected property is set to true, if it is we add the Contact to the selectedContacts list
    for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
        if(cCon.selected == true) {
            selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
        }
    }

    // Now we have our list of selected contacts and can perform any type of logic we want, sending emails, updating a field on the Contact, etc
    System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
    for(Contact con: selectedContacts) {
        system.debug(con);
    }
    contactList=null; // we need this line if we performed a write operation  because getContacts gets a fresh list now
    return null;
}


// This is our wrapper/container class. A container class is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects. In this example a wrapper class contains both the standard salesforce object Contact and a Boolean value
public class cContact {
    public Contact con {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    //This is the contructor method. When we create a new cContact object we pass a Contact that is set to the con property. We also set the selected value to false
    public cContact(Contact c) {
        con = c;
        selected = false;
    }


   }
}
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <!-- In our table we are displaying the cContact records -->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
                <apex:column >
                    <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Email}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Now use this code as reference you will get all selected value in your code. You can replace the checkbox with inputradio. and it will solve your problem.

Comment: hi amit can u please check the code,records are not displayed if click the button

Answer (score 0):

The below code will do the following functionalities,

1. Displayed Account records in Page block table with Radio Button option.

2.You can choose only one account at a time by selecting a radio button.

3. After account record is selected click on "View Contact Records" button. This will display the list contact records related to the selected account.

Controller class

```
public class RadioButtonController {
    public string selectedAccountId {get;set;}
    public List < Account > accounts {get;set;}
    public List < Contact > contacts {get;set;}
    public RadioButtonController() {
        accounts = [SELECT Name, Type FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }
    public PageReference getSelected() {
        System.debug('Entered account selection block');
        selectedAccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accid');
        contacts = new List < Contact > ();
        return null;
    }
    public void viewContacts() {
        if (selectedAccountId != null) {
            contacts = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: selectedAccountId];
            if (contacts.size() == 0)
                contacts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Force Page

```
<apex:page controller="RadioButtonController">
    <apex:form>
        <!-- Account page block -->
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Viewer">
            <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!If(accounts !=null && accounts.size>0,true,false)}">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc" width="100%" id="accTable">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                        <input type="radio" name="<strong>selectRadio</strong>" id="radio">
                        <br/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" status="buttonStatus" reRender="cntblock">
                            <apex:param name="accid" value="{!acc.id}" />
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                        </input>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!acc.Type}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <!-- Action status block -->
            <apex:actionStatus id="buttonStatus">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:commandButton value="View Contact Records" disabled="true" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:facet name="stop">
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:commandButton value="View Contact Records" action="{!viewContacts}" reRender="cntblock" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <!-- Contact Block -->
        <apex:outputPanel id="cntblock">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Available Contacts" rendered="{!If(contacts != null && contacts.size>0,true,false)}">
                <apex:pageblockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="con" width="100%" id="cntTable">
                        <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageMessage summary="No Contacts Found" severity="Info" strength="3" rendered="{!AND(contacts == null, selectedAccountId != null)}" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: i want to choose multiple accounts at a tym,

Comment: Do you need to do anything with them or just display them? If you need to do something with them then you need a wrapper class as mentioned above in the other answers. Technically, if you just want to display them you use a remote action and JavaScript as see below.

Comment: vat ever i select in table should come after i hit button

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a javascript array of ids and convert the javascript array to string from the front end using JS_ARRAY.toString() and send the parameter via string and catch it via string property and process this input via a comma(,) delimiter.

First you have to get the `Id` in your Query. `cust =[select Id, Name,Phone from Account limit 10];`. To use multiselect you have to use `type="checkbox"` for your `<input` field. Populate the `value` field with `ID` value. Create a javascript array and push the ids on `onclick` method of the checkbox. Convert this javascript array to string and assign to hidden input field `theHiddenInput`.

In controller get this and convert to a List or do as per your requirement.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="showingselectederadiovaluescontroller">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Ids = [];
        function assignHiddenValue(chkvalue){
            Ids.push(chkvalue); 
            var sel = document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.theHiddenInput}');
            sel.value = Ids.toString();
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="myForm" >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cust}" var="a" >
                <apex:column >
                    <input value="{!a.Id}" type="checkbox" name="chosen"  onclick="assignHiddenValue(this.value);"/>
                </apex:column> 
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!selectedAccountId}" id="theHiddenInput"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!showSelectedAccounts}" value="click to show selected radio value"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class showingselectederadiovaluescontroller {
    public List<Account> cust {get;set;}
    public string selectedAccountId{get; set;}//String formatted array which we will receive from VF page. 
    public String[] selectedAccountIdList{get;set;} //To convert into the list from the string formatted input.
    public showingselectederadiovaluescontroller (){
        cust =[select Id, Name,Phone from Account limit 10];
    }
    public void showSelectedAccounts() {
        selectedAccountIdList = convertStrToList(selectedAccountId);
        System.debug('@@@@ '+selectedAccountIdList);
        //To-Do - Pass this list to VF page and show accordingly
    }
    public String[] convertStrToList(string str) {
        String[] listToReturn = new List<String>();
        if(String.isNotBlank(str)) {
            for(String eachStr : str.split(',')) {
                listToReturn.add(eachStr);
            }
        }
        return listToReturn;
    }    
}
```

Debug Log Screen

[image]

Comment: iam not able to display selectedAccountIdList in the vf page,please help\

Comment: in the @@@ debug,printing null

Comment: Can you please post your updated code?

Comment: i just copy pasted your code,

Comment: @sahi - Please see my above Debug Log Screen, It is working for me. Please compare your code with mine, I am sure you will find the issue.

Comment: yes,working now and i want to use selectedAccountIdList in vf page,,i want to display selected records below.please help me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To show the selected radio button when clicked you can attached a click method to the radio. Here is a quick example. This is quick and dirty, but maybe get you started.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class showingselectederadiovaluescontroller {

    public List < Account > cust {get;set;}
    public Account selectedAccount;

    public showingselectederadiovaluescontroller() {
        cust = [select Id, Name, Phone from Account limit 10];
    }

    public Account getSelectedAccount() {
        return selectedAccount;
    }

    public void setSelectedAccount() {
       // Get the selected Account Id from the page
       String accountId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountId'); 
       selectedAccount = [select Id, Name, Phone from Account WHERE Id = :accountId LIMIT 1];
    }
 }
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="showingselectederadiovaluescontroller">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="showSelected" action="{!setSelectedAccount}" reRender="pbAccount">
            <!--Assign the accountId parameter to use in the controller method-->
            <apex:param name="accountId" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>    
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cust}" var="a">
                <apex:column>
                    <!--Since the Id is unique we can set it to the Id (or we could have used a data attribute) and the onclick will run the setSelectedAccunt with this id-->
                    <input type="radio" name="chosen" id="{!a.Id}" onclick="showSelected(this.id)"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:outputPanel id="selectedAcctContainer">
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbAccount" value="{!selectedAccount}" var="s">
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Phone}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>       
            </apex:outputPanel>         
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: HI Andrew L,i want to select multiple accounts,,can u pls suggest me ,how to do

Comment: Are you going to display all the accounts on the page or do you need pagination? If you need pagination, a wrapper class or JavaScript/jQuery is required.  What is your overall goal? That would help.

Comment: in your code ,u have used input radio,it allows us to select only one record right,,my requirement is to select more than one record with the help of <apex:inputxcheckbox

Answer (score 0):

Page (note: I added some bootstrap link references for quick styling and I normally use jQuery and JavaScript, but this is all JavaScript):

```
<apex:page controller="showingselectederadiovaluescontroller">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cust}" var="a">
            <apex:column >
                <input type="checkbox" id="{!a.Id}" class="account-select"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>          
</apex:form>
<button onclick="getSelectedAccounts()">click to show selected accounts</button>
<table class="table">
    <caption>Selected Accounts</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>       
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot> 
    <tbody id="selected-accounts"></tbody>                                
</table>          
<script>
function getSelectedAccounts() {
    var chkAccounts = document.querySelectorAll('input.account-select:checked');
        var accountIds = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < chkAccounts.length; i++) { 
            accountIds.push(chkAccounts[i].id);          
        }
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('showingselectederadiovaluescontroller.setSelectedAccounts',
            accountIds,                                      
            function(result, event) {
                if (event.status) {
                    var accountTable = document.getElementById('selected-accounts'); 
                    accountTable.innerHTML = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        var row = accountTable.insertRow(i);
                        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= result[i].Name;
                        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= result[i].Phone;
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(event.message);
                }
            }, {
            escape: true
        });  
        return false;
}               
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class showingselectederadiovaluescontroller {

public List <Account> cust {get;set;}

public showingselectederadiovaluescontroller() {
    cust = [select Id, Name, Phone from Account limit 10];
}

@RemoteAction
public static List<Account> setSelectedAccounts (String[] accountIds) {
    return  [select Id, Name, Phone from Account WHERE Id in :accountIds];
}
}
```

Comment: using above code,selected records are not displayed

Comment: I just copied and pasted my code in a gain, so give it a go. Also, what browser are you using? Also, you can try to remove the with sharing and change the controller and remote action methods to global to see if that makes a difference. Also, I would open your browser developer console to see if there is an error (before/after) you click the button.

Comment: chrome iam using